# Is projecting lazy, eager or explicit in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

I've learned about lazy loading, eager loading with .include and explicit loading with .load(), but something that confuses me is when you project in a query and explicitly request a navigation property like this:

```
var address = from a in context.Addresses
              select {a, Name = a.Contact.Name}
```

Here Contact is a navigation property in Addresses that links to a Contact entity.

I tried with both lazy loading on and off and it works both ways. I wonder when I request my data like this, am I eager loading or deferred loading? My understanding that only one query will be made to the database which means it's eager loading, except in this case only the "Name" property of the Contact entity will be loaded, as opposed to the entire Contact entity if I were to use context.Addresses.include("Contact")? Does it make a query like this more efficient than eager loading with .include() ?

Some clarifications will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading, eager loading and explicit loading works in the most common scenarios. Projection is replacement for eager loading because it can also load related entities with single query. Using projection make sense if you need to load entities with some complex query because eager loading doesn't work in these cases. Use projection if you need:

- Any kind of join or aggregation in the linq query. As I know `Include` is ignored once you start using manual joins.
- Any kind of filtering or sorting in navigation property. `Include` can only load all related entities from navigation property without any sorting. Once you need to apply any where condition or order by on related entities you can't use `Include` and you must use projection.

Answer (score 0):

It's lazy evaulation as it won't execute until something enumerates over address.

Eager loading is normally used to describe an entity object's navigation properties being pre-loaded but in this case you are not directly materializing any entity objects as you are projecting onto an anonymous type.

If you access a.Contact.Name rather than Name you'll most likely cause another database hit as you haven't eager loaded the Contact object of Address, you specifically selected and projected the Name property onto an anonymous object.